# Google Analytics: Do I need URL address?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-analytics

I am a complete Google Analytics beginner and would appreciate a help with a basic question.

I am developing HTML, CSS and JavaScript based applications which are further uploaded into  an iOS application to present your applications in a fancy way. Therefore my application is a **hybrid application (half JS web site, half mobile app)**.

I would love to see users' activity in my app when they are browsing through it and I thought GA might work well with it - but the problem is, that the outer app doesn't provide me with any URL of my inner JS app (the inner web site's URL is file:///).

At this page ([link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/04/22/how-to-integrate-google-analytics-tracking-into-your-apps-in-7-minutes/)), I found that URL is not really important, that it is the tracking code which is important. So I used a dummy URL, added the GA snippet into my application and uploaded it in iPresent. I can't see no live activity though... :/ It also says the measuring is not installed (not used at a home page).

So I am wondering - is the URL really important?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found out that URL is not needed**. This type of problem can be solved by using GA Measurement Tool
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Validate your hit here:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

Answer (score 0):

URL (or page path) is only important if you want to report on data based on which URLs your visitors went to.

If you app doesn't use URLs at all, perhaps it fits better with the "app" model where you are sending *screen name* data instead of *page* data. You can read more about the differences between web and app views here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553

Comment: The thing is, my app is just a pure front-end based JS application that is further injected into an iOS mobile application (=iPresent). I can't program anything in iPresent, only this inner JS application... That's why I would probably need to use website model, but it needs to work without URL... Any ideas how to solve this? Thank u!

Comment: None of that matters. App vs web only affects the type of data you send and how your reports look in Google Analytics. It doesn't matter if it's *actually* an app or not.